# Access Photogallery in android browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cordova

I want to access the android mobile photogallery from the android browser.

I included the `cordova.js` in my application (basically a `mvc3` application), but it doesn't work for me (navigator.camera is undefined).

Do I need to include any other files/libraries in my application apart from cordova.js? 
Is it possible to access the device resorces in browser or not?

Comment: There's a full example that contains accessing photogallary [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture).

Comment: but in my application i am getting navigator.camera as undefined. I am trying from the android browser.

Comment: I want to access the device features using device browser(android and ios).